# What data type should i use for time (not date)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, data-structures

If i have an event with a date, and then want the user to state a start time and a end time, what is the best  / most standard way to represent that in the db?

Is there a time data type or should i just have start_at end_at in the database and convert whatever is in the UI to that?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using MySQL you can use TIME datatype to store a time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the timestamp. Why not use it to mark the start and end points in time. You can transform them in your application to some more useful Time/Date type.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TIME type. The format is: HH:MM:SS. Source: [Link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/time.html)